# Status of "self doubt" question

Tags: discussion

The question:

- [how can you cope with disappointment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132970/how-can-you-cope-with-disappointment)

Seems to me like a good fit for this site if it can be clarified a bit. I don't think this question should necessarily be moved to Workplace.SE. I mean you could, but then you're not dealing with the specific psychological issues of creating graphic designs or art. Which in my mind do belong on this site, because it's about graphic design. Also Workplace.SE seems a strange suggestion as the person is a student.

Even if you disagree, you might want to elaborate as to why you think this shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: I agree, although the question needs some work before it's valid.

Comment: The way the question is worded there's nothing specific to graphic design, hence my close vote. Of course if it gets edited to be more specific then I'd retract my vote.

Comment: @Luciano i disagree the fact that your internal vision disagrees with outcome is related to especially graphic design

Comment: Having been through both an art & graphic design education and then many years after that, an architectural design education, I agree that the specific nature of the design educative process and the inherently personal nature of the body of work and process development make this type of question uniquely fitted to our SE versus workplace SE - though I also feel the specific question to which we refer needs some serious refinement to become more generally useful.

Comment: @joojaa fair enough, that's why we have votes and meta to discuss it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm trying *very hard* to not be negative and offensive as I write, because that's NOT what is in my heart. And I'm aware many **read** what I write with an "angry" voice in their head, even if that's **not** *my* voice.

I understand the plateaus one can hit and how difficult those can be to overcome. I suspect anyone in any sort of creative field has faced them more than once.

However, this isn't *really* a question. It's venting. Which is understandable, but not on-topic or the point of this site. This is seeking more personal "life coaching" for how to overcome one's own hurdles. And there is no *actual* information in the question. It's merely a few emotion-driven sentences. That's all.

If a question were posed because someone was angry with a client.. and they posted merely 4-5 sentences explaining their anger while providing no details about *anything* else, that question would be closed. Merely because the emotion is more of a somber tone doesn't make a "question" *more* valid.

**If** it were a valid question *much* more detail and specitivity would be needed. I mean, no one here knows the user. Random advice on how to deal with disappointment is **not** "graphic design" in my opinion.

Again, I feel for the user. And having once been a first year student I can understand the hurdles but without *specific* project details and issues, it's not a valid question.

In addition, there are questions here about being more creative or breaking out of current mindsets... or using elements more effectively. Edits to this question to make it more on topic would merely mean all of those could possibly be *duplicates* - and that assumes the user ever returns to edit the question.

I "get" that it can be difficult to cast close votes when you empathize with the sentiment, but I look at this as "business" not "personal". A question shouldn't remain open merely due to empathy.

**Of course**, I'd be all in for a *conversation* about the topic in person or via chat. And if asked by a student I'd stop and spend time helping. but that doesn't mean it belongs on a Q&A site.

Comment: Very valid points! I do think the question needs an edit. I think that will clarify things (if OP comes back of course)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with joojaa (though I'd like to hear the community on this).

My take is there is a LOT going on for first year graphic design students in terms of adapting to how design works. Learning to separate your own identity from your ideas and your failures, understanding that there is no single correct answer, feeling comfortable in showing your ideas to the teacher, comparing yourself to your classmates, etc.

It's a design education question and I know these have not always been well received in the past but if OP comes back with clarifications, I'll be very happy to answer it.

Comment: FWIW, at this point I understand the question is not currently answerable and needs an edit. This should motivate a closing but more likely as "too broad", than as "off topic"